# Межсценная работа в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть главное меню - это первая сцена, из неё можно переходить на сцену с картой - это вторая сцена и в этой второй сцене есть кнопка выхода обратно в главное меню, при нажатии на которую происходит возврат в главное меню, но кнопки уже не реагируют никак, они сбрасывают события, которые были на них повешены, почему?

Comment: Хорошо бы привести какие-то выкладки, иначе очень сложно будет помочь.

Comment: Где вы вешаете события? В `Awake`? Скрипт помечен как `DontDestroyOnLoad`?

Comment: События вешаю на кнопки через инспектор, не в скрипте. Да, у меня есть объект, который имеет этот скрипт в качестве компонента и этот объект перемещается по сценам через "DontDestroyOnLoad".  Извиняюсь за запоздалый ответ, не было возможности зайти на этот форум.

Comment: "этот скрипт" - имел в виду, что есть скрипт, который принимает кнопки в инспекторе, этот же скрипт висит на том объекте, который перемещается по сценам.

Comment: Разобрался с этим вопросом, там как раз дело было в использовании "DontDestroyOnLoad", я ведь и до того, как задать вопрос думал на этот метод, но ваш вопрос натолкнул на размышления и пришло озарение) Но также появился другой вопрос, который нужно будет задать, если сам не найду ответ.

Comment: Можете оформить в виде ответа, может кому-то поможет. А другой вопрос задать потом отдельно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело было вот в чём, есть объект-пустышка, на котором висели скрипты меню, контроллер и т. д. и этот объект-пустышка перемещался на вторую сцену и из этой сцены была возможность перемещаться обратно на первую сцену, т. е. сцену с меню, но при переходе на эту первую сцену не работали кнопки меню, как раз таки из-за того, что скрипты меню были прикреплены к объекту пустышке, который перемещался по сценам методом "DontDestroyOnLoad". Открепил эти скрипты от этого объекта, оставив только скрипт контроллера - заработало!